# Pass single DataContext instance between pages

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, datacontext

I'm developing a WPF xBap application using MVVM.  I'm in a position where I'd like to pass a single instance of a ViewModel to use as a DataContext between 2 Pages from which the user will navigate back and forth.

I'm having some issues and I'd just like to know if someone can confirm if this is actually possible.

I've seen many similar posts but none that just fits with my question so I'll just reiterate that it's not 2 views creating their own instance of a ViewModel as a DataContext,  but 2 views sharing a single instance.

Many Thanks

David

Comment: Um, yes. Just assign the same object as the DataContext for both views. Have you run into an issue?

Comment: I have a telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn bound to the same property in both views and for some reason view 2 cannot load the ItemsSource. I was just confirming that this could be done.  Must be something else but for the life of me I cannot work it out.

Comment: Yes, following on from Zak's comment you can easily do this by declaring the dataContext in a top-level (parent) view, which holds the 2 views you want.  And assuming they are in the same logical tree, both views will automatically have the same datacontext as the parent.  If not, you can also just reference the parent's datacontext on each of the views (something like <... DataContext={StaticResource=...).

Comment: Ah, I just read your comment.  So assuming you setup the datacontext correctly (as I commented above) then check your binding is setup correctly.  Post the xaml for us if that's easier.  Also, have you checked any other properties that are common across the 2 views?  Do they work or not?

Comment: Cheers Guys, I've managed to get this working.  When I made an unrelated change in the ViewModel after the 2nd view was ctor'd the ComboBox would not load,  but when I made the same change before calling the 2nd view ctor everything was ok.  Its a mystery to me, thanks for the input.